# How is the field of a non-moving charge static if field changes propagate only at the speed of light?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

Let us consider a charged particle which is static with respect to a frame of reference $A$. Now suppose that I accelerate the charged particle to a speed $v$.

Now when I accelerated it to a speed $v$, during the course of acceleration the particle would radiate EM waves. Now these EM waves would keep propagating (at least the according variation of EM fields would go on) even when the particle has attained a uniform velocity. Now when the particle is moving with a uniform velocity, there would be time variations in E field and B field as per a particle with uniform velocity. Now let's bring this particle to rest by a retarding force. Again, during this course of acceleration the particle would radiate EM waves which will again start propagating all around.

But now the particle would have come to rest and its field should be static. But due to it's early origination there must be some points in space where the EM waves due to the first acceleration would have reached but about the subsequent events might not have . But this would lead to the implication there must be some points in space where the EM field due to a static electron is still undergoing variations and is not constant.

Can we express a static electric field as a superposition of two EM waves as in this case?
Can we explain this sufficiently within the purview of classical theories?

Comment: yes. special relativty + electrodynamics

Answer (score 2):

The relativistically correct electromagnetic fields of any charge are given by the [Lienard-Wiechert potentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential).

The waves emitted during the course of acceleration *do not belong* to the field of the charge, since the waves are *vacuum solutions* of Maxwell's equations.

So, the presence or absence of radiation has nothing to do with the field being "static" or not.

In the fully relativistic treatment, the fields of the stopped charge are not static in time throughout all space though, but depend on the retarded time as is detailed in the Wikipedia article about Lienard-Wiechert. In the volume of space around the charge to which the "stop" has already propagated, the field is static, however.

Comment: Could you elaborate the part "The waves do not belong to the field of the charge "

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: EM waves are *vacuum solutions* (i.e. valid solutions of Maxwell's equations in a region free of charge and current) - they exist without need for the presence of a current or charge, and in this sense, they do not belong to the field of any object - they exist on their own. "The field" of an object is the part of the electromagnetic fields that is obtained by solving Maxwell's equation for the charge-current distribution of said object.

Comment: you mean only for the final configuration?

Comment: And regardless of the categorization of the field the net electric field in the presence of a static charge can be time varying at some points ,i.e. at distant points ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: If the charge was moving before it became static, then yes, that is what Lienard-Wiechert tell you - the information "the charge is static" propagates only at the speed of light, after all.

Comment: But at the same time we cannot exactly say which charge was moving initially and which was not , right?

Comment: Moreover, won't the information about changing fields at far away points propagate back to the points where the field is supposed to be stationary ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: Stop thinking about this in the vague terms of "information propagating" and look at the *actual* solutions of Maxwell's equations. The Lienard-Wiechert potentials are the full and correct way to get the electric and magnetic fields of a uniformly moving charge. If you change the velocity of the charge, you'll have a patched-together solution. Also, we cannot say whether a charge was moving in the past or not, no.

Comment: But, isn't it so that those signals do have a potential to communicate these changes at far off points to nearby points ?